# Graph of infinity

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Create a function that plots the $\infty$ symbol when plotted.

My function is $$|y|=|\sin x|$$ 
For $\{x: -3\le x \le 3\}$

Bonus points if your function is **NOT** mathematically equivalent to mine.

Double bonus points if the function is simpler than mine, or draws a more beautiful symbol.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate

Comment: There is no such function.  What you stated is not a function.  It fails the vertical line test.  The infinity symbol fails the vertical line test so no function graphs to it.

Comment: Your *relation* extends infinitely in either direction and at the points where it crosses the axis is not circular but pinched.  So it isn't an infinity sign.  (It's more like a double helix....)

Comment: I don't know what the vertical line test is. What about those functions that draw logos, breasts, etc.

Comment: If we restrict the domain of $x$, can't we plot the $\infty$ sign? I don't have access to a tool to allow me plot this relation. I __merely__ theorised that it would plot infinity. I noticed that $|y| = |x|$ gave a cross sign. And since $sin(x)$ gives a horizontal "S", I theorised |y| = |sin x| will give an infinity symbol.

Comment: @fleablood, I've modified my answer, so that my relation draws the infinity sign.

Comment: @TobiAlafin You can plot graphs at Wolfram Alpha [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Cy%7C%3D%7Csin(x)%7C+for+-pi+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+pi).

Comment: @fleablood `It fails the vertical line test` Any closed curve will fail the vertical line test. This includes the standard [lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli) most often identified as *the* infinity sign $(x^2+y^2)^2=2a^2(x^2-y^2)$.

Comment: the lemniscate isn't a function.  No closed curve is the Cartesian graph of a function.  None of those logos, breasts etc. are functions either.

Comment: |y| = |sin x| for 0 <= x <= 2 pi is not a function.  It is a curve.  It is a reflected sin wave but the the tips will be pinched into a right angle and not a rounded circular curve.

Comment: Those that are complaining that it is not a function it is trival to convert those definitions to a function $ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} ) $

Answer (score 2):

Take any smooth, concave curve which passes through the origin at a finite, positive slope, then has a vertical tangent at its next root, for example $y = x \sqrt{1-x}$:

[image]

Then mirror it along both axes to complete an infinity-like sign e.g. $|y| = |x| \sqrt{1-|x|}$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Viviani's Curve is a nice way to see the infinity in a 3 dimensional figure by intersecting a sphere of radius $2a$ with a cylinder of centered at $(a,0,0)$ of radius $a$ this intersection:

$$V(t)=\bigg < a(1+ \cos(t)), a\sin(t), 2a\sin\Big(\frac t2\Big)\bigg>$$

Comment: I think you mean "Vivian**i**'s Curve"

Comment: Indeed I did...